# as of blender 3.2 what is best way to go from slow rug particles to Realtime texture?

Tags: particles, texture-baking, unity, unreal-engine, pbr

I rendered this:
[image]

which up close looks like:

[image]

But it is intended for indoor house in game engine. Specifically isaac sim as it's for robotics, but think of it as Eevee, Unity, Unreal, etc game PBR material.

Obviously I cannot just take a top view render and keep as albedo, as lighting and shadows and camera angles will all look terrible.

But how can I 'generate' a texture with AO, roughness, color, and normals and heightmap to make a believable render that would look similar to if I rendered the scene with the actual particles. Also of course it should be tileable, but with eg one tile filling up about 2m square.

What I have rendered is just simple particle system with 1000 particles and 1000 interpolation, so 1 million particles.

Question: How do I go from here to get a game-ready pbr texture map, with option for AO,roughness, normals, and heightmap for parallax occlusion mapping?

(also note that being for robotics, there is likely to be a camera fairly close to the ground so it's important that the texture look believable from low hights. ie imagine a 12 inch tall teddy bear running around in a carpeted house in a video game. how would I get that kind of effect in realtime. Most carpet textures I see are 'industrial' style like at a hotel, where they are very flat and not like the kind usually found in homes that are fully carpeted, eg 1.5cm fibers.)

RESULT: based on answer below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - I've done my best to label the appropriate maps. I must point out that a material such as this is not ideal to create in blender, as blender's shader system does not handle *Parallax Occlusion Mapping* nor *Tesselation* natively. Because of this, I used a heavily subdivided cube (in cycles) as a basis for displacement to try and "approximate" the effects of occlusion mapping - you can just use the B&W map used as it's input for the height map (not worrying about the displacement node).

[image: Carpet]

Comment: wow that's really nice. I tried to replicate it but mine is not displacing. I subdivided my cube into 6 million vertices.  I updated my question with my result. maybe can you share you blend file?

Comment: Under the material settings, there are 2 places you can enable true displacement (they "hid" the second one) - one is under "displacement", the other is under "settings" below it (you have to expand the menu) - change where it says "Displacement: Bump Only" to "Displacement: Bump and DIsplace".

Comment: marking this answered though it didn't actually answer how to go from particles to maps but i guess that isn't really feasible, and this answer really helped

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - I don't know if I can "answer" that per se, but as far as I know particles to maps is not possible - I don't think any kind of (texture) co-ordinate data exists for particles until they are realized.